# How can I make ion-scroll scrollToTop() in ionic2?

Tags: javascript, ionic2

Well, I know that with content, you can scroll to top.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#scrollToTop

However, I have the ion-scroll directive like this:

```
  <ion-scroll scrollY="true"  class="detail-cause">
    <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
    <div [innerHtml]="product.body"></div>
  </ion-scroll>
```

How can I make just this ion-scroll directive to scroll to the top?

Thanks,